# Ich nahm das Buch mit ins Bett. (why is there no "mir"?)

Tags: verb

*Ich nahm das Buch mit ins Bett.*

I feel like I'd like to write a "**me**" after mit. Like I take the book with me.

Is this because **mitnehmen** has already the "**with me**" included?

I don't know like to describe it but I hope you got the idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could phrase it in English without "me": "I took the book into bed." Keep in mind that "with" is a preposition in English and requires an object, so a "me" is grammatically needed even though it's not necessary for the meaning; the meaning of "I took the book with into bed" is clear even if it's ungrammatical. The German *mit* is also a preposition, but in this case it's just a prefix and doesn't require it's own object. You could easily turn the *mit* into a preposition: *Ich nahm das Buch mit mir ins Bett.* But then who else would the book be with?.

Side note: There are a number of phrasal verbs in English where "with" is a particle instead of a preposition. An example is "cope with". There is no object needed for "with" needed here either, but it's still a transitive verb so an object is needed for the verb itself. You can tell the difference by using the verb in a question:
"What can you cope with?" -- Grammatical, "with" is a particle
"What can you bring with?" -- Ungrammatical, "with" is a preposition.